# How to implement web-based graph editing for Neo4j?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, playframework, vaadin, neo4j, graph-visualization

I am building an application that stores semantic graphs in Neo4j. I want to have a web interface that allows to edit the graph, e.g. adding new relationships with couple clicks and drag'n'drops, and editing node properties through simple popup windows.

Preferably the graph editor would be JavaScript-based, but I'm also interested in hearing about other options (Flash, Java applet, etc.).

Neo4j would be either in server or embedded server mode. Embedded mode is not acceptable, because I want to access the server also using Neo4j's own web interface.

I'm also trying to find a suitable web framework. I have mostly experience of Rails, but recently I've been interested in Vaadin because it provides neat UI components out-of-the-box. Play seems also nice, but there doesn't seem to be that many modules for the newest version.

So I've been thinking about following frameworks for the web application:

**Play**
Well, mainly because I like Scala and Play seems to have good support in the most recent version. However, maybe a bit too small ecosystem (support, amount of libraries)?

**Rails**
I like Rails very much. However, I don't know about any graph plugins or integrations for Rails. Maybe I should create one myself (where to start?)? Which JavaScript graph lib would fit well in Rails?

**Vaadin**
Actually I came across Vaadin just recently. Vaadin has good IDE support and many ready-made UI components. Vaadin seems to have at least one decent graph addon ([Cytographer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/cytographer)). I don't have any experience of Cytoscape or how it works with Neo4j, though..

### Some JavaScript libs that I came across:

- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)
- [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)
- [VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/)
- [InfoVis](http://thejit.org/)

And just to make it clear: I'm not looking for a *charting* tool, but a *graph* drawing and editing tool, that integrates well with the underlying web application framework and Neo4j.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're mixing two, quite different topics: If you are about to choose JS library, then choosing framework for data rendering is just a matter of YOUR taste.

Comment: he's interested in data editing, not just data rendering

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer. For the front end look at jsPlumb. There are several toolkits that let you do graph visualization, but jsPlumb provides ways for visual graph editing.

The project homepage is here: http://jsplumb.org/